# T-SQL - Can I do this without hard-coding the Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have other SQL that results in a query which I stored in a table for testing and sanitizing the data.  The following query accomplishes what I want to do for this specific case (i.e. continue to have 3 rows of data with the PiValue filled in properly from other columns, based on the value of the PiTag and or the FieldName column).  I will be sending CONTRACT_DAY, PiTag and PiValue to a timeseries database called PI (PiSystem) using other tools.

Note that my case statement is hard-coding the values in the FieldName and PiTag column.  So if they ever added a new field, I would have to change, and redeploy my query. So I'm wondering if there is a clever way in T-SQL to do this without then "case" logic that I have provided.  I was thinking maybe "pivot" could help.

[image]

```
SELECT METER_IDNUM
      ,CONTRACT_DAY
      ,VOLUME
      ,HEATING_VALUE
      ,ENERGY
      ,FieldName
      ,PiTag
      ,case when PiTag = 'ABC-Raw_Volume' then VOLUME
            when PiTag = 'ABC-Raw_Energy' then ENERGY 
            when PiTag = 'ABC-Raw_GHV' then HEATING_VALUE 
       else 0
       end as PiValue 
        
  FROM [dbo].[NealTempDemo]
```

I put it on SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94803/1

Create data SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NealTempDemo](
    [METER_IDNUM] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CONTRACT_DAY] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [VOLUME] [float] NULL,
    [HEATING_VALUE] [float] NULL,
    [ENERGY] [float] NULL,
    [PiTag] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FieldName] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[NealTempDemo] ([METER_IDNUM], [CONTRACT_DAY], [VOLUME], [HEATING_VALUE], [ENERGY], [PiTag], [FieldName]) VALUES (N'12345', CAST(N'2023-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 2325498, 1009.3034147640643, 2347136, N'ABC-Raw_Volume', N'VOLUME')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[NealTempDemo] ([METER_IDNUM], [CONTRACT_DAY], [VOLUME], [HEATING_VALUE], [ENERGY], [PiTag], [FieldName]) VALUES (N'12345', CAST(N'2023-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 2325498, 1009.3034147640643, 2347136, N'ABC-Raw_Energy', N'ENERGY')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[NealTempDemo] ([METER_IDNUM], [CONTRACT_DAY], [VOLUME], [HEATING_VALUE], [ENERGY], [PiTag], [FieldName]) VALUES (N'12345', CAST(N'2023-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime), 2325498, 1009.3034147640643, 2347136, N'ABC-Raw_GHV', N'HEATING_VALUE')
GO
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: For a query to automatically pick up new columns it would have to be dynamic - which is not really what SQL is intended for.

Comment: There might be a way to dump the contents into XML and then use the value of `FieldName` to pick out the XML element corresponding to the desired value. The same might be possible using JSON. However, if you add a new column, I expect you will still need to modify your posted query to include it as its own column.  Why select based on `PiTag` instead of `FieldName`?

Comment: @TN - I could have used either PiTag or FieldName.  This query is going into BizTalk which builds XML to send to a WebService which wraps the PI database server.  So it's just part of a series of steps, some of which already exist for other systems at my client.   There are other dozens of other columns in source tables that I am not showing.  Maybe I'm over-engineering it.

Comment: The table design looks weird. Why do you have all 3 measures in it but only one tag.

Comment: For a moment, I thought I could do something tricky like `CAST('' AS XML).value('sql:column(sql:column("FieldName"))', 'float') AS PiValue`, but discovered that SQL Server only accepts a string literal values as a `sql:column()` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will convert the entire current row to XML and then use the `FieldName` value to select the desired column element to extract the value.

```
SELECT METER_IDNUM
      ,CONTRACT_DAY
      ,VOLUME
      ,HEATING_VALUE
      ,ENERGY
      ,FieldName
      ,PiTag
      ,X.XML.value('(*[local-name()=sql:column("D.FieldName")]/text())[1]', 'float') AS PiValue
      --,X.XML
FROM NealTempDemo D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT D.*
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) AS X(XML);
```

The above assumes that all selected values are convertible to `FLOAT`.

Results:

| METER_IDNUM | CONTRACT_DAY | VOLUME | HEATING_VALUE | ENERGY | FieldName | PiTag | PiValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2023-01-01 00:00 | 2325498 | 1009.30341476406 | 2347136 | VOLUME | ABC-Raw_Volume | 2325498 |
| 12345 | 2023-01-01 00:00 | 2325498 | 1009.30341476406 | 2347136 | ENERGY | ABC-Raw_Energy | 2347136 |
| 12345 | 2023-01-01 00:00 | 2325498 | 1009.30341476406 | 2347136 | HEATING_VALUE | ABC-Raw_GHV | 1009.30341476406 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IzGgp81y) for a working demo.

**Caution** Just be aware that this approach may add costly overhead to your query - especially if your data contains "dozens of other columns".  If your data is coming from several different sources joined together, you might want to look at applying the XML operation at a point closer to the source where data bloat isn't as bad.

Comment: I made a minor change for performance improvement: added `text()`.

Comment: Very nice, even though it's kinda over-engineered too :D

Comment: Very clever, even though I do XML, I wouldn't have thought of that.  Also, hi to my old friend Yitzhak!